# Parser EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:s (java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Mon Nov 23 2015 08:00:00" (at offset 0)

Tags: java, android, date-format

I have problem to parse my string:

```
String dateString = "Mon Nov 23 2015 08:00:00";

try {

     DateFormat readFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss");
     Date date = readFormat.parse(dateString);
     return date;

    } catch (ParseException e) {
      Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
      return null;
    }
```

The problem is

```
 java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Mon Nov 23 2015 08:00:00" (at offset 0)
```

Can you please help me. thanks.

Comment: What does `Locale.getDefault()` return?

Comment: I remove Locale.getDefould() but not working

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem with locale `en_US`.

Comment: But what IS your default locale?  Did anything odd happen on that day, such as a change in daylight savings times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `UK` locale:

```
String dateString = "Mon Nov 23 2015 08:00:00";

try {

     DateFormat readFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.UK);
     Date date = readFormat.parse(dateString);
     return date;

    } catch (ParseException e) {
      Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
      return null;
    }
```

Comment: I tried this, but return null;

Comment: it is strange. it works for me

Comment: Try to use `Locale.ENGLISH` or `Locale.US`

Comment: `Locale.ENGLISH` is a good idea, because a Locale is both a country and a language.  If the language of the default locale isn't English, then `Locale.US` or `Locale.UK` won't help them, so Monday might not be `Mon` and November might not be `Nov`.  However, until the OP tells us what `Locale.getDefault()` returns, all we can do is guess.

Comment: Hi Arthur, its working now....thank you so much!